# The video set in Open Graph from my backend is not displayed

Tags: asp.net, next.js, facebook-opengraph

Why do videos from my own backend not work in the player with OpenGraph support, while videos from other websites do work? I'm using NextJS for the frontend and .NET for the backend.
UPD. Removed links that will no longer work soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "og:video" tag at the end of the link should have a file type of ".mp4", not necessarily the same as the video type, but one that is commonly used for videos.

[HttpGet("Stream/{id}.{trash?}")]